# How do I make .htaccess work on the current directory and not subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod rewrite to access my PHP files in the root directory of my website indirectly. Currently, I have something like this,

```
RewriteRule ^(blog|about|page3|etc)$ /$1.php [L]
```

But what I would like to use is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

So that I wouldn't have to update my .htaccess file whenever I wanna add a new page to my website. The problem with this however is that it affects my subdirectories too. Which makes CSS, javascript, images unaccessable because it redirects to "/dir/example.png.php".

So what is the best solution here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `.htaccess` to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

After starting the rewrite engine, it will first check to see if the requested file is an actual file on the system, or if it is actually a directory. If it is neither of those, it will execute the rule, which in this case is to try and find the file by appending `.php` and serving that up.

Subdirectories, images, CSS and the like will be fine because they will step out of the rewriting once they are found.

Comment: Problem with this one though is it gives me a server error whenever the file is not there.

Comment: That's not good then. Will update if there's another way other than the one suggested by Gumbo.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it with filters to ignore sub-directories. That way you only have to change it if you add a sub folder. You'll need to add a line like **Sosh**'s if you have images or other files in the folder

The following would ignore "images" and "js" sub folders and redirect everything else

```
RewriteRule   ^images*   -  [L]
RewriteRule   ^js*       -  [L]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$     /$1.php   [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this (note the !):

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|zip|gz|html|xml)$ index.php
```

Comment: That won't ignore sub folders