# How do I use .htaccess to block a directory and all subdirectories without RewriteEngine?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, subdirectory

So far, I have:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1/8
```

This blocks the top directory (not root directory) of the folder I am trying to hide from anyone else except me, but it does not block subdirectories. I still want to have access to the directory, and all the examples I have seen use the Rewrite Engine to completely block access from subdirectories. How do I block the subdirectories as well? This is the opposite of the first suggested question:

[How do I make .htaccess work on the current directory and not subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200348/how-do-i-make-htaccess-work-on-the-current-directory-and-not-subdirectories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I thought the closed beta packages I was testing were overriding my .htaccess file with their own, but they did not override any directory permissions.

At Kamil's suggestion, I looked into my httpd.conf and noticed that AllowOverride was set to None for the root directory of my web server. Setting it to All worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your quoted config works as you need.

If it does block only the *current directory* but you're able to access a subdirectory of it - this is how I understand your description - it means, you changed the access rules with some further `.htaccess` and/or config in `httpd.conf` i.e. by `allow from all`

Comment: Your answer was close but not exact. I would vote up your answer if I had enough reputation myself.

Comment: @NobleUplift thanks. Do you still have some problems or is it solved already? What was the problem?

Comment: I made an answer to explain the solution.