# How to refer to the current directory in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, apache2, global-variables

I need to get dynamically the current directory in which my .htaccess file is located. Is that possible ? (A variable maybe ?).

Something like : `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}`

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : If with regular expressions ? how should it look like ?

Comment: did you check this [list](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#Mod_Rewrite_Variables) ?

Comment: my be this helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200348/how-do-i-make-htaccess-work-on-the-current-directory-and-not-subdirectories

Comment: Apparently, it is impossible to obtain the current directory path in .htacess files via an expression. Just one of a handful of remarkable limitations of using Apache directives in .htaccess files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Apache still does not have pathinfo($,PATHINFO_DIRNAME) function like PHP does.

So on, there have been solutions based on the usage of %{REQUEST_URI}, like this example:

```
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /path-dirname/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Regarding your issue, this may work for you:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^.+/$ %1 [R=301,L]
```