# Limiting .htaccess to current directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

I'm trying to limit the scoop of a .htaccess file to only it's current directory, but cannot seem to get it to work. I know I have to use the  tag, and put my folder there.
So this is what I've come up with, but it doesn't work:

```
<Directory "/home/user12345/domains/testing.com/public_html">
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule ^Home index.php?show_page=home
     RewriteRule ^Contact index.php?show_page=contact
</Directory>
```

I've also tried removing the folders at the beginning of the path, with no success.
Also I would like to know if I have to add the whole path to my RewriteRule like this:

```
     RewriteRule ^Home home/user12345/domains/testing.com/public_html/index.php?show_page=home
```

Is that necessary?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200348/how-do-i-make-htaccess-work-on-the-current-directory-and-not-subdirectories

Comment: Thanks Nabil, but i've read that question already before asking mine, and i don't really see how the answer given there answers my question. Seems like the TS there also wanted to do something else at the same time.

Comment: Seems i've misread and the <Directory> directive cannot be used in .htaccess ?